# Scala for loop unexpected compilation error

Tags: scala

```
object Main {
  val list = List[Long]()
  val map1 = Map[Long, List[Long]]()
  val map2 = Map[Long, Long]()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for {
      a: Long <- list
      b: List[Long] <- map1.get(a)
      c: Long <- b
      d: Long <- map2.get(c)
    } yield d
  }
}
```

The type of a,b,c,d has been declared just for easy to analysis the code.

Then I get the unexpected compilation error:

```
Error:(10, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : List[Long]
 required: Option[?]
      c: Long <- b
```

The type of `b` is a List, I think `c` should mean each item in the List `b`

Why the compiler expect `b` should be a Option something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing options with lists. If you convert your option to a List it works:

```
  b: List[Long] <- map1.get(a).toList
```

Remember that a for comprehension is just syntactic sugar for `flatMap`.  This is actually performing a `flatMap`on the result of `map1.get(a)`:

```
  b: List[Long] <- map1.get(a)
  c: Long <- b
```

which expects an option as a result. To avoid confusion you should always use the same type you started with, which is `List` in this case.

Another option would be to skip `b` entirely and directly flatten the result of the first map:

```
a: Long <- list
c: Long <- map1.get(a).toList.flatten
d: Long <- map2.get(c)
```